# Extending PHP with C++?

Tags: php, c++, plugins, php-extension

I have a performance intensive routine that is written in PHP that I'd like to port to C++ for a performance increase. Is there any way to write a plugin or extension or something using C++ and interface with it from PHP? WITHOUT manually editing the actual PHP source?

Comment: Worth noting there's a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492014/how-to-start-writing-a-php5-extension-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a PHP plugin in C++ with the help of [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). It's doable, but it may take a while to get used to the SWIG-compilation cycle. You can start with the [SWIG docs for PHP](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html).

**Update**
As @therefromhere has mentioned, I greatly recommend that you get the book [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232704X). There is almost no documentation to be found online (at least there wasn't in late 2008, early 2009 when I did my PHP plugin). I had to rely on the book for everything. Although sometimes Google Code Search is helpful for finding sample code.

Answer (score 20):

As [Remus says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c/1110760#1110760), you can extend PHP with C/C++ using the Zend API.  The linked tutorial by [Sara Golemon](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021) is a good start, and the book [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X) by the same author covers the subject in much more detail.

However, it's worth noting that both of these (and pretty much everything else I found online) focus on C and don't really cover some tweaks you need to get C++ extensions working.

In the `config.m4` file you need to explicitly link to the C++ standard library:

```
PHP_REQUIRE_CXX()
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(stdc++, 1, PHP5CPP_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

Any C++ library compile checks in the `config.m4` file will also require linking the C++ lib:

```
PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,,
[
  AC_MSG_ERROR([lib $LIBNAME not found.])
],[
  -lstdc++ -ldl
])
```

#### EDIT - and here's how to specify g++:

Last, and not least, in order to choose the C++ rather than C compiler/linker when building the extension, the **6th** parameter to `PHP_NEW_EXTENSION()` should be `"yes"`.  ie:

```
PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(your_extension,
                  your_extension.cpp, 
                  $ext_shared, 
                  ,
                  "-Wall -Werror -Wno-error=write-strings -Wno-sign-compare",
                  "yes")
```

From the [PHP build system manual](http://www.tufat.com/docs/php_manual/internals2.buildsys.configunix.html#internals2.buildsys.configunix.finishing), the parameters are:

1. The name of the extension
2. List of all source files which are part of the extension.
3. (optional) `$ext_shared`, a value which was determined by configure when PHP_ARG_WITH() was called for
4. (optional) "SAPI class", only useful for extensions which require the CGI or CLI SAPIs specifically. It should be left empty in all other cases.
5. (optional) A list of flags to be added to CFLAGS while building the extension.
6. (optional) A boolean value which, if "yes", will force the entire extension to be built using $CXX instead of $CC.

<strike>I couldn't work out how to get the configure script to set g++ as the compiler/linker instead of gcc, so ended up hacking the Makefile with a sed command to do a search replace in my bash build script:</strike>

```
phpize
./configure --with-myextension
if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
# Ugly hack to force use of g++ instead of gcc
# (otherwise we'll get linking errors at runtime)
   sed -i 's/gcc/g++/g' Makefile
   make clean
   make
fi
```

Presumably there's an [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) command that would make this hack unnecessary.

Comment: Mind tat setting compiler flags this way is a bad practice. This makes it impossible to use different compilers. Either make it compiler dependent or let it to the user. The option can be used for common options like -D though. Additionally it's quite likely that -Wall and -Werror will make trouble - PHP is written in C and C++ in some cases is a bit stricter so you might fail in PHP headers. We fixed many of those issues in 5.4,but some C++ Warnings might still occur.

Comment: @johannes fair enough, this was project was for internal use only so that wasn't a problem for me.

Comment: It might become a problem if you switch to a different platform or compiler one day. clang becomes popular these days for instance. And I mostly added it for future developers hitting this page :-)

Answer (score 2):

PHP itself a collection of loosely related libraries. See http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021 for a tutorial how to write your own.