# c++ php and static library

Tags: php, c++, static-libraries

I've created a library.a that contains a .cpp and .h files with a lot of classes, nested classes and methods. I would like to include this static library inside a php example and try to work with it. I would like to mention that I am new to php. I've tested my libray.a inside a test.cpp file and it works. How can I create a test.php and test my library.a?If it;s possible please send me some examples.

I would like to mention that i am working in ubuntu. g++ was my compiler.

Thx for advices! Appreciate!

EDIT:
I WOULD LIKE TO MENTION THE FACT THAT I DON'T WANT TO EXPOSE MY .CPP CODE. I JUST WANT TO USE MY .H AND .A FILES.

Comment: Possible [reading suggestion](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486).

Comment: i don't want to use my .cpp and .h files. i want to use my .a library. i don;t want to expose my .cpp code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending PHP with C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c)

Comment: You could doubly wrap the library in another C++ wrapper... but why, don't you have access to the source? You have to write some bridging code one way or another, you can't just add a random library to PHP and magically expect PHP to provide an interface to it.

Comment: yes i do have access to the source file: .cpp and .h file. how to create a bridging code?

Comment: @sunset, yes this is fine, when you write your PHP extension you'd just call the library functions.  One issue you'll have is that you'll need to compile your static library with `-fPIC` (on gcc), and you'll have the usual issues associated with compiler compatibility when distributing C++ libraries.  BTW the reason you need `-fPIC` is because PHP extensions are dynamic libraries.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c/1966341#1966341

Comment: @therefromhere; i've compiled my library using g++ -c -static -L -lb library.cpp -o library.o and the using : ar rcs library.a library.o. is it ok? I would like to mention that i've never used php. i am new with it. can you please write step by step how should i work? is there a link with an example based on my quesion?

Comment: Follow the tutorials in the question I linked and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

An `.a` file is not a self-executable library. It is static object code. It cannot run by itself.

PHP doesn't have loaders. It can't load a `.a` file, neither your very own operating system can.

An `.a` file needs to be accompanied by the appropriate headers (`.h` files).

If you want to use native code within PHP, you must use PHP's interfaces. See, just like anything built with C/C++, PHP has it's own definition of what a string (or most data types) look like.

In short, you have two options:

- use PHP's headers and interface your code directly with PHP
- use a library wrapper which connects your calls to PHP
- make your library into an executable and call it with PHP*

*PHP has plenty IPC methods, so this is actually quite feasible.

Comment: if i want to use the first option can u please explain how to use the php headers? can i include in .php the .h and .a that i have?

Comment: sorry for my stupid questions:). Can you please extend your answer? i am new to php. if i create a dynamic library i won;t need the .h file ?

Comment: No. PHP **is interpreted**. C **is native**. If you want to do it this way, see @therefromhere's comment.