# Creating .so file on windows for C++ Static Library to be used in PHP

Tags: php, c++, windows, eclipse, makefile

Actually we are required to use C++ Static Library in PHP, for that we are required to create .so . 
Just to be specific we are working on Windows Platform, so make / ./configure etc are not available here for making php extension or we are not able to figure that out.

Any help either on creating ".so" file for C++ static library on windows or 
steps to create make and configure files for C++ Static library on windows.

thanks in advance....

Comment: did you try to use cygwin and/or msys for configuring/building/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files with extension .so are *usually* [unix-based dynamic libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#File_naming).
The equivalent for that in Windows is *usually* a .dll file.
In the case of PHP extensions, it might be a good idea to read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)

Related questions:
[c++ php and static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244482/c-php-and-static-library)
[Extending PHP with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c)

Answer (score 1):

you use dll's in a windows enviroment

```
 LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

as an example in httpd.conf
or

```
 extension=php_gd2.dll
```

in PHP.ini . Recompile the code with gcc if you need it in a unix enviroment