# can html and c++ be linked without any external application?

Tags: html, c++, executable

i am working on a project which requires my c++ based code to run in a web page. taking the simplest example of "hello world" code in c++, is it possible to link this code to an html document, any help would be appreciated.

Scripting constraints: html/php/asp.net (asp.net only if this is not at all possible with html/php)

Comment: _"is it possible to link this code to an html document"_ No. There are c++ to javascript compilers like emscripten though.

Comment: You could [transpile it to Javascript](https://kripken.github.io/mloc_emscripten_talk/gindex.html#/) using emscripten

Comment: But c++ does not do this out of the box, so to speak. It is not php-style embeddable in html-pages.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes - provided your users are using chrome:

https://developer.chrome.com/native-client

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but working with yor constraints, is to make this "hello world" program output the whole html, and use it as a [cgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). Or use php or asp to call this exec and redirect its output.

But **this is not** having the source code embedded in the html, like php does, but compiling the C++ to an executable and calling it from php. You can even [extend php with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c).