# Is it possible to call/use a C# class in a PHP project?

Tags: c#, php

I have a PHP project which accesses an API. the project works perfectly well using the test uri for the API.

When I started using the live uri I started getting authentication errors.

After asking around and eventually finding complete documentation, I found out that the Authentication Token needs to be passed as an Http request header. The token is generated by a C# class

Short of rewriting the project in C# is there a way of making the class and it's functions available in the PHP project?

Comment: Compile the class into an Assembly then: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php (Assuming Windows)

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ab0c2ef-ff20-4044-9edc-8836d32e0e0f/instantiate-c-class-in-php?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: rewrite that one class in PHP? If the auth token is generated according to a particular algorithm (there should be a language-independent spec which defines how it must be done?) then you can just re-implement that? But are you sure this is the only way to get the auth token? It doesn't sound like a conventional implementation of a token service.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c

   It stands to reason that if you make a C++/CLI wrapper for this C# class you could utilize this question's answer.