# Use C or C++ libraries as PHP extension

Tags: php, c++

Minutes back I read something like "it should be possible to link the C++ library as a php extension".

- Is it really possible?
- if yes, which is better, newly written extension or a linked library (efforts and performance wise).
- Also can you guys point me to some How-to or related doc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632160/how-to-make-a-php-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, check these out:

http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/

[How to start writing a PHP5 extension in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492014/how-to-start-writing-a-php5-extension-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The [following link](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/) will probably answer all your questions. Basically yes, it's possible to link C++ lib as PHP extension.