# Passing parameters from c++ to php

Tags: php, c++, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP and C++ pass data between each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936280/can-php-and-c-pass-data-between-each-other)

I want to pass some parameters from C++ to PHP, though I don't know what to use. Will `$_POST` and `$_GET` suffice or are there better options for these kind of connections?

The PHP is just a simple "data to OpenOffice document" script. This script needs to receive some parameters from a C++ application and collect data according to those parameters from a MySQL database.

**EDIT:**

Found the answer, I could achieve what I wanted simply through [URL-passing](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php)

Comment: This depends on what you need.

In certain situation just accessing the URL would be enough, but if you want more complex functionality (like a web service in php that allows you to add/edit/delete entries, and grab complex information), you should consider REST or SOAP.

Comment: Please be more specific: What are "these kind of connections"? Are both applications running on the same machine? Is the target a CLI PHP script, a web application, a web service?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of question #9936280. Question #9936280 deals with initiating data transfer in PHP, this question deals with initiating data transfer in C++. Note that *duplicate* means *This question has been asked before* and not *The answer is similar to a question asked before*.

Comment: @Resitive Do not provide an answer by editing your question. Add a proper answer like I and user1929959 did. Also, if your PHP script is available as a web application (i.e. it has a URL), you should have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) to start the php intepreter, passing the name of the script and any additional arguments as part of the `command` parameter. You can then access the arguments passed to the script using the [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from similar questions, take a look on [executing a C++ application over the internet with PHP](http://archive.networknewz.com/networknewz-10-20020311Executing-A-C-Application-Over-The-Internet-With-PHP.html).